# Converting pseudo-namespaced classes to use "real" namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, automated-refactoring

I am at the point of refactoring a rather large project that has been developed using a pseudo-namespacing convention, like:

```
<?php
// Filename: Classes/OtherSubNamespace/Foo.php
class Vendor_OtherSubNamespace_Foo
{
}
```

I want to use a namespace using PSR-4 recommendations and to refactor the class to look like:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\OtherSubNamespace;

<?php
// Filename: Classes/OtherSubNamespace/Foo.php
class Foo
{
}
```

The difficulty is not only in refactoring the class itself, but also all other classes that refer to this class in the project.

PHPStorm seems to do a good job using the `Move Class` and `Rename Class` refactoring tools, but it has no functionality to do a batch refactoring job.

I also had a look at [PHP Refactoring Browser](https://github.com/QafooLabs/php-refactoring-browser) but found no relevant functionality.

Are there any other tools out there that can recursively refactor class names / introduce namespaces that I am not aware of?

Comment: Hey Valentin, is this still relevant or did you managed to solve it in some way? If so, could you share your solution?

Comment: Hey  Tomáš, I did not find a tool that could do that. I invested some time and use the refactoring feature in PHPStorm. Luckily there were enough Unit-Tests to give me an indication on what is failing. Good luck!

Comment: Allright, I'm glad you make in your own way!
I've added it to my sniff ideas for coding standard: https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/issues/59

Comment: Work in progress: https://github.com/RectorPHP/Rector/pull/88